# Modal form not validated and closing on submit jquery validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a modal which I am showing using AJAX. As soon as I click submit in the modal it closes and the fields are also not validated.

```html
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title">Contact Number</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <form method="post" id="user_verified_mobile">
    <input type="text" name="mobile_number" placeholder="Mobile Number" class="form-control" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Verify" />
  </form>
</div>
```

```js
jQuery('form#user_verified_mobile').on('submit', function(e) {
  if (!jQuery('form#user_verified_mobile').valid()) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  jQuery("form#user_verified_mobile").validate({
    rules: {
      mobile_number: {
        required: true
      },
    },
    messages: {
      mobile_number: {
        required: 'Please enter mobile number',
      }
    },
    success: function(label, element) {
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems inside your code...

```
jQuery('form#user_verified_mobile').on('submit', function(e) {

    if (!jQuery('form#user_verified_mobile').valid()) { ...

    jQuery("form#user_verified_mobile").validate({ ...
```

1. You're calling `.valid()` before you've called `.validate()`.
2. You're calling `.validate()` inside of a `submit()` handler.

The `.validate()` method is used for **initializing** the plugin on your form and needs to be called before invoking `.valid()`.  **HOWEVER**, there is absolutely no need for a `submit` handler or `.valid()` or `.preventDefault()` in this case ***because the plugin captures the events and blocks default submit automatically***.

Just call `.validate()` on the page ready handler and everything else is automatic.  Note, if the form does not exist in the DOM upon page ready, then call `.validate()` right after the `form` is created.

```
jQuery(function() { // document ready event

    jQuery("form#user_verified_mobile").validate({ // initialize plugin on form
        ...
```

DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/d67twLr8/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/d67twLr8/1/)

I also don't know why you have blank `success` and `submitHandler` callback functions within your `.validate()` call.    **With an empty `submitHandler`, NOTHING will happen when the form is valid.**  Remove them entirely for default behavior or override with your own functions... never leave empty.